# What is the best way to deal with incapable reporting manager?

Tags: professionalism, work-experience, project-management, conflict-resolution

You have developed a product that could directly save $700 per month for the organisation. You have told about this to your reporting manager (a part-time consultant) and, he without seeing the product directly turned down to take it forward. He always tries to get the project outsourced to his affiliates partner (maybe he will have his cut in doing so). You presented the same to other stakeholders too and they are impressed and would like to go ahead with it and suggested to keep working on the same, as they had few suggestions to implement. You are working on this and your that product is quite close to cut the winning ribbon.

The problem here is, none of the stakeholders now taking the responsibility to talk to your reporting manager who turned down your idea without having a single glance at it, because he is quite close to the Managing Director of the company.

TBH, the reporting manager has never cared of you as a team. Even in his maiden visit to the office in a month, he wouldn't feel to check on what you or your team are working on. Absolutely, no direction and no Support you'll have from him.

So my questions are:

1. How to handle such a reporting manager?
2. How to push the product ahead?
3. If you push the product then expect a backfire from your reporting manager that can impact your appraisal and performance.

If I were you, How would you have handled this situation?

Answer (score 2):

> You are working on this and your that product is quite close to cut the winning ribbon.

It's crucial to understand what led you to work on the development of this product? Was it assigned to you by your reporting manager or someone else you report to? Is your reporting manager aware of you spending time on this? Was it asked of you to work on this product? Does he expect you to spend time on something else? Or is this something you are working on your own in your extra time?

In general, a subordinate may have little to no say say in the decisions taken by the reporting manager.

You can sure recommend him a product/process enhancement but it's generally his/her decision. There may be reasons behind his choice that you may not be aware of.

> What is the best way to deal with incapable reporting manager?

If I were in your position, I wouldn't do anything. If the reporting manager has dismissed the idea, and as long as it's putting me in bad light or affecting me in a negative manner, I'd comply with his decision.

Note, this would be just a realistic way to handle the situation. If you and the other team members are not in a position to influence the reporting managers decision, you better not.

> TBH, the reporting manager has never care of you as a team, even in his maiden visit to the office in a month, he wouldn't feel to check on what you or your team are working on. Absolutely, No direction and No Support you'll have from him.

If changing the circumstances is not something that I control, I would re-consider if I am in the right circumstances.

> 3. If you push the product then expect a backfire from your reporting manager that can impact your appraisal and performance.

Apparently you have the answer yourself. If I were in your position, I'd think practically.